# How to trick Windows into believing there is internet connection

Tags: windows-10, networking

I am a security analyst and I need to assess a Windows UWP program. I have a virtual machine with no internet connection and machine that will answer all requests to the first machine (this second machine have no internet connection also).

Normal programs will usually try send requests with no problem at all but in this case it looks like UWP programs uses some Windows API to check if there is internet connection.

Question: Is there a way into tricking Windows10/11 into thinking there is Internet connection? How?

(By "no internet connection" I mean when windows shows this state: https://www.thewindowsclub.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/Ethernet-Not-Connected-No-Connections-are-available.png)

Comment: The network connection status indicator (NCSI) just attempts to download a text file from a known microsoft server (http://www.msftconnecttest.com/connecttest.txt). You can set up your own NCSI responder to fool it: https://blog.superuser.com/2011/05/16/windows-7-network-awareness/. No guarantees that your individual UWP app doesn't have its own thing internally, but that's what windows uses at least

Comment: Thanks @Cpt.Whale, that was very useful actually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try the open-source
[alwaysonline](https://github.com/Jamesits/alwaysonline) :

> AlwaysOnline is a HTTP and DNS server which mocks a lot network/internet/portal detection servers.

If you have Visual Studio Code or Visual Studio, you could use its
simulator. See the article
[Run UWP apps in the simulator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/run-windows-store-apps-in-the-simulator?view=vs-2019):

> To debug or test your network cost-aware code, the simulator can mimic properties of a network that are exposed through the ConnectionProfile object returned by GetInternetConnectionProfile.